# T-SQL function not thread safe after UPDLOCK

Tags: sql-server, multithreading, t-sql

I have a simple getNextID procedure that retrieves an id value in a table and increments the value by 1.  It was built with some multi threading in mind, but it appears that the UPDLOCK in the procedure doesn't actually make it thread safe as was intended and I'm trying to understand why.  The idea was that the UPDLOCK during the initial select would prevent any other threads from performing that select until the update at the bottom of the procedure was complete; however, that doesn't appear to be the case since I'm getting duplicate values when two threads fire at the same time.

After reading a few other threads, I think what might be happening is the UPDLOCK is preventing other thread from *updating* the row, but it isn't preventing them from performing the initial select before the update.  So both threads are performing the same select (retrieving the same value), then thread 2 is waiting for thread 1 to update and then thread 2 updates the row to the same value.  Am I understanding what the lock is doing correctly?  Would the proper way to accomplish the thread-proofing be to wrap it all in a BEGIN/COMMIT TRANSACTION?

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE getNextID (
    @NextNumber int OUTPUT
    ,@id_type VARCHAR(20)
    )
AS
BEGIN

    SELECT @NextNumber = (last_used_number + 1)
    FROM its_id_sequence WITH (UPDLOCK)
    WHERE id_type = @id_type

    UPDATE its_id_sequence
    SET last_used_number = @NextNumber
    WHERE id_type = @id_type
END
```

Thanks!

Comment: Anytime you try to roll your own identity you are fighting a losing battle. There are a lot of challenges surrounding this. Why not just use the already fully functional identity property? If you don't like gaps (which of course are perfectly normal) you could switch to using a sequence instead if you are on 2012+.

Comment: @SeanLange: I don't think a sequence has a guarantee of being gapless. _Maybe_ if you specify `no cache` on sequence creation, but that has performance implications. I've never had anyone able to reasonably explain the business requirement of having no gaps in the sequence.

Comment: @BenThul The sequence itself would be gapless. But if you use it as a primary key it will end up with gaps as soon as a row is deleted. What the OP is doing here is basically the same thing as the already build sequence.

Comment: @SeanLange: From the documentation: "When created with the CACHE option, an unexpected shutdown, such as a power failure, can lose the sequence numbers in the cache.".

Comment: But regardless what is the point of generating a gapless sequence of numbers? There will always be a gap when a row is deleted so the mindset of gapless numbering is a never ending battle. Accept the gaps and move on.

Comment: I always prefer the DB handle it for me!  Sadly, in this instance, the number being generated actually isn't the primary key.  It's a number being used to group several rows together, so it isn't actually unique.  If I'm not mistake, the identity property (we're on 2008, so sadly sequence isn't an option) generates a unique value for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way would be to slightly use a different version of an update query and obviously warp the whole thing into a transaction.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getNextID
     @NextNumber INT          OUTPUT
    ,@id_type    VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @NextValue TABLE (NextNumber int);

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    UPDATE its_id_sequence
      SET last_used_number = ISNULL(@NextNumber, 0) + 1
     OUTPUT inserted.last_used_number INTO @NextValue(NextNumber)
    WHERE id_type = @id_type

    SELECT @NextNumber = NextNumber FROM @NextValue

COMMIT TRANSACTION;

END
```

So you update first without reading the value, and once updated then get the value and use it.

Comment: I've never seen that OUTPUT inserted syntax before.  Thanks for that!  So the best way to make this thread safe is to perform an update and select within a transaction.  Just for my understanding, assume the transaction started with a select query and then had an update (so something like SELECT (id +1)  and then finishes off with UPDATE id SET id = (id+1)).  Would thread 2 be able to perform the select before thread 1 committed or would thread 2 wait until the entire thread 1 transaction was finished before starting its own transaction?