# In Micrsoft SQL is an UPDLOCK hint sufficient to avoid deadlocks in an SP that either inserts if not exists or updates otherwise?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a C# program with multiple threads that calls an SP to get a unique incrementing value.

I'm trying to prevent deadlocks using query hints UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK.

The SP

1. Selects value from a table,
2. insert if the value is not found (initial value is 1)
3. Or updates the table by incrementing the value from the first select
4. Returns the incremented value in an output parameter.

Here the table

```
CREATE TABLE MyCounters(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Questions

1. Will a single UPDLOCK be sufficient in the first select to prevent deadlocks?
2. Or do I need to select with UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK?
3. Or do I need a second dummy select with UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK to only lock the entire table for inserts but not for updates?

I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32958103/t-sql-function-not-thread-safe-after-updlock) but there no insert is used.

Below the simplified SP and after that a script I used to test in 2 tabs in SQL management studio. With only a single UPDLOCK the test script works (i.e. no deadlocks and counters at the correct values).

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @Key nvarchar(3)
SET @Key = 'AA'
DECLARE @counter bigint
SET @counter=NULL

-- *** Question 1 *** Will a single UPDLOCK be sufficient in the first select to prevent deadlocks?
-- *** Question 2 *** 1. Or do I need to select with UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK?
SELECT @counter=Counter FROM MyCounters WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE Key = @Key

IF (@counter IS NULL)
BEGIN       
    -- *** Question 3 *** Or do I need a second dummy select with UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK to only lock the entire table for inserts but not update?
    -- lock the entire table before inserting (select into variable)
    --DECLARE @temp bigint
    --SELECT TOP 1 @temp = Counter FROM MyCounters WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

    SET @counter=1
    INSERT INTO MyCounters ([Key],Counter) VALUES (@Key, @counter)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @counter=@counter+1
    UPDATE MyCounters SET Counter = @counter WHERE Key = @Key
END

SELECT @Key, @counter

COMMIT
```

Below the test script (which I ran in multiple tabs in SQL management studio)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05' --to give me a chance to start the script in multiple tabs

DECLARE @i int
SET @i=0
WHILE @i < 100
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Key nvarchar(3)
    SET @Key = 'A'+CONVERT(nvarchar(10),@i)
    DECLARE @counter bigint
    SET @counter=NULL
    SELECT @counter=Counter FROM MyCounters WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE Key = @Key

    IF (@counter IS NULL)
    BEGIN               
        -- lock the entire table before inserting (select into variable)
        --DECLARE @temp bigint
        --SELECT TOP 1 @temp = Counter FROM MyCounters WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)

        SET @counter=1
        INSERT INTO MyCounters ([Key],Counter) VALUES (@Key, @counter)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @counter=@counter+1
        UPDATE MyCounters SET Counter = @counter WHERE Key = @Key
    END

    SELECT @i, @Key, @counter

    SET @i = @i + 1

END;

 
COMMIT
```

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern

Answer (score 1):

> -- *** Question 1 *** Will a single UPDLOCK be sufficient in the first select to prevent deadlocks?
> -- *** Question 2 *** 1. Or do I need to select with UPDLOCK and HOLDLOCK? SELECT @counter=Counter FROM MyCounters WITH (UPDLOCK) WHERE
> Key = @Key

In in the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, the `UPDLOCK` will be released when the statement completes. Specify `UPDLOCK,HOLDLOCK` to retain locks until the transaction commits or rolls back.

I suggest you change the clustered primary key from the `IDENTITY` column to the natural key column `Key` or make the unique constraint the clustered index.  This will improve performance. If you don't actually use the `Id` column, remove it entirely. Throwing an unused `IDENTITY` surrogate key on tables is a common anti-pattern.

```
--clustered unique constraint
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyCounters(
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Key] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT UQ_MyCounters_Key UNIQUE CLUSTERED,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )   
);

--remove unneeded surrogate key
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyCounters(
    [Key] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_MyCounters PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [Counter] [bigint] NOT NULL
);
```

Also, add `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` to procs with explicit transactions to ensure the transaction is rolled back immediately after errors or client timeouts.